# Can we implement KeyBindings using KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, key-bindings

Just the matter of interest, is there a way that `KeyListener` can do the same work as `KeyBindings`, I mean Overriding *keyListener's* method(s) and listen to multiple keys (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>somekey</kbd>).

I know, it's kinda stupid idea, but as I said, just a matter of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using a flag:

```
KeyListener kl = new KeyListener() {

    boolean controlPressed = false;
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
            controlPressed = true;
            return;
        }

        if(controlPressed) {
            // CTRL is pressed, you can check here for other keys:
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                //CTRL + A was pressed
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) {
            controlPressed = false;
        }
    }
};
```

---

As camickr pointed out in comments, the other way would be to use the `isControlDown` method from `KeyEvent`:

```
if(e.isControlDown()) {
    //CTRL is pressed
}
```

Comment: If `CTRL` is pressed, after that what to do? How to listen to another key?

Comment: `KeyListener` listens to all keys on the keyboard, so you just have to check which key was pressed by using the key code provided in the `KeyEvent`. I updated the answer with an example

Comment: Not sure why you would use a flag. The KeyEvent contains the information about the Alt, Control, and Shift keys.

Answer (score 3):

The KeyEvent contains the information you need for Alt, Shift and Control keys:

```
if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && e.isControlDown())
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative is you could do this which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> down and also <kbd>A</kbd>

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
     if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A,  InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK).getKeyCode())
           //Code Here
     }
}
```